# Is NFS file locking destroyed by the nfs server bind-mounting the directory being nfs shared?

Tags: nfs, lock, bind-mount

I have a directory `/persistent/pacmanPkgCache` which is both:

- nfs-shared to other machines
- bind-mounted to `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`

Does having this directory nfs-shared and bind-mounted at the same time destroy nfs' ability to handle file locking?

Could a program on the nfs server working in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` bypass the locking mechanism nfs implements, if another machine has the same file locked?

I could switch it so the nfs-shares are from the `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` location, since that is where programs on the nfs server will most commonly access the files through.

It's a long story why the directory is being accessible in both locations - easiest to ignore that part.  :-)

Comment: I'd expect that bind mounts are transparent as far as NFS locking semantics.  I think the remapping happens fairly early in path resolution.